# GLCD Library : GLCD.H & UTILITY.H

Tags: lcd, lpc

I am working upon Interfacing GLCD with LPC2148.

Please share library for GLCD Library : To include in program

```
#include "Glcd.h"
#include "Utility.h"
```

Else share path where i can get ?

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

To find proper GLCD library it is important to know your GLCD drive
by the way,I'm using this library (my driver ili9290)

[link1](http://wikisend.com/download/496756/GLCD.rar)

[linke2](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8134879542/GLCD.rar.html)